# port mapper failure in NIS configuaration

Tags: fedora, yum, nis

I am working on `fedora 17`, i am trying to configure `NIS server`, I installed **ypser, rpcbind, ypbind** packages by '**yum**' command, everything is fine, but at the last step, when hostname has to be store in the database, then after pressing **ctrl+d** and '**y**' i receive port mapper failure, but host is successfully added into database.

I receive following error..

```
At this point, we have to construct a list of the hosts which will run NIS servers. dlp is in the list of NIS server hosts. Please continue to add the names for the other hosts, one per line. When you are done with the

list, type a   control D.

next host to add: vinita

next host to add:                  # Ctrl + D key

The current list of NIS servers looks like this:

vinita

Is this correct? [y/n: y] y        # answer yes

We need a few minutes to build the databases...

Building /var/yp/server.world/ypservers...

Running /var/yp/Makefile...

gmake[1]: Entering directory `/var/yp/server.world'

Updating passwd.byname...

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating passwd.byid.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating shadow.byname.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating group.byname.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating group.bygid.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating hosts.byname.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating hosts.byaddr.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating rpc.byname.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating rpc.bynumber.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating service.byname.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating service.byservicename.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating netid.byname.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating protocols.bynumber.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating protocols.byname.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failureUpdating mail.aliases.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper failure# netgrp shadow publickey.

Failure to send 'clear' to loca ypserv : RPC : port mapper network ethers bootparams printcap.

gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/var/yp/server.world'

vinita has been set up as a NIS master server.

Now you can run ypinit -s vinita on all slave server.
```

---

can anyone help me to resolve this problem, due to this problem client is unable to connect to my server.

Comment: This seems [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) because it is not about programming or software development. You might want to ask about this on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not the problem of configuring and installing NIS server and others. The problem you are facing is your Operating System. I'll recommend you to put these **shell commands** in your fedora Terminal before you do install/configure your ypbind, ypserv and other packages.

```
$ user@user sudo su
```

Then enter your password

```
# root@user apt-get clean
# root@user apt-get autoclean
# root@user apt-get update
# root@user apt-get upgrade
# root@user apt-get dist-upgrade
# root@user reboot
```

Then you can use all your `ypserv` and `ypbind` commands, Try this, I believe it will definitely work.

Comment: Is it working now ? Because I've recently installed it in Ubuntu, and It is running perfect here.